# Xcode module import errors

Tags: ios, xcode, chat, message

I'm trying to add the AMBubbleTableViewController module to my app (https://github.com/andreamazz/AMBubbleTableView), and I followed the instructions, but I got a lot of errors and I don't know why.

These are the errors, any idea?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:


"_AMOptionsBubbleDetectionType", referenced from:
      -[Chat viewDidLoad] in Chat.o
  "_AMOptionsBubblePressEnabled", referenced from:
      -[Chat viewDidLoad] in Chat.o
  "_AMOptionsBubbleSwipeEnabled", referenced from:
      -[Chat viewDidLoad] in Chat.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AMBubbleTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Chat in Chat.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_AMBubbleTableViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Chat in Chat.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and there is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
// Bubble Table setup

[self setDataSource:self]; // Weird, uh?
[self setDelegate:self];
[self setTitle:@"Chat"];

// Dummy data
self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:@[
                                                    @{
                                                        @"text": @"He felt that his whole life was some kind of dream and he sometimes wondered whose it was and whether they were enjoying it.",
                                                        @"date": [NSDate date],
                                                        @"type": @(AMBubbleCellReceived),
                                                        @"username": @"Stevie",
                                                        @"color": [UIColor redColor]
                                                        },
                                                    @{
                                                        @"text": @"My dad isn’t famous. My dad plays jazz. You can’t get famous playing jazz",
                                                        @"date": [NSDate date],
                                                        @"type": @(AMBubbleCellSent)
                                                        },
                                                    @{
                                                        @"date": [NSDate date],
                                                        @"type": @(AMBubbleCellTimestamp)
                                                        },
                                                    @{
                                                        @"text": @"I'd far rather be happy than right any day.",
                                                        @"date": [NSDate date],
                                                        @"type": @(AMBubbleCellReceived),
                                                        @"username": @"John",
                                                        @"color": [UIColor orangeColor]
                                                        },
                                                    @{
                                                        @"text": @"The only reason for walking into the jaws of Death is so's you can steal His gold teeth.",
                                                        @"date": [NSDate date],
                                                        @"type": @(AMBubbleCellSent)
                                                        },
                                                    @{
                                                        @"text": @"The gods had a habit of going round to atheists' houses and smashing their windows.",
                                                        @"date": [NSDate date],
                                                        @"type": @(AMBubbleCellReceived),
                                                        @"username": @"Jimi",
                                                        @"color": [UIColor blueColor]
                                                        },
                                                    @{
                                                        @"text": @"you are lucky. Your friend is going to meet Bel-Shamharoth. You will only die.",
                                                        @"date": [NSDate date],
                                                        @"type": @(AMBubbleCellSent)
                                                        },
                                                    @{
                                                        @"text": @"Guess the quotes!",
                                                        @"date": [NSDate date],
                                                        @"type": @(AMBubbleCellSent)
                                                        },
                                                    ]
             ];

// Set a style
[self setTableStyle:AMBubbleTableStyleFlat];

[self setBubbleTableOptions:@{AMOptionsBubbleDetectionType: @(UIDataDetectorTypeAll),
                              AMOptionsBubblePressEnabled: @NO,
                              AMOptionsBubbleSwipeEnabled: @NO}];

// Call super after setting up the options
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 0, 0)];
```

}

Comment: This is a linker error that occurs because the symbol and class definitions are not included in any of the source files being compiled. Ensure that the Compile Sources build phase includes the `AMBubbleTableViewController.m` and `AMBubbleGlobals.m` files.

Comment: Thanks!! the problem has been solved. I needed to fix some more stuff but it fixed the problem. again thanks !

Comment: If this comment helped solve your problem, please accept the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will frequently see this kind of linker error when the sources files containing a particular definition you are using are not being compiled, despite their declarations being in a header file you are importing.

You can fix this by adding the appropriate source files to the "Compile Sources" build phase of your project.

In this particular case, you need to include the `AMBubbleTableViewController.m` and `AMBubbleGlobals.m` files.